# DNS/Domain not working

Tags: debian, virtualhost, domain, vps, apache2

I have domain, pointed to my VPS. I made VH in apache to serve simple index.htm file to check if everything works fine.

Unfortunatelly something is wrong because page is not found(http://zoofi.me).

Here's my DNS configuration:
[image]

I added VH via some tutorial that i found and it looks like this:

```
GNU nano 5.4       /etc/apache2/sites-available/zoofi.me.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@zoofi.me
  ServerName zoofi.me
  ServerAlias www.zoofi.me
  DocumentRoot /var/www/zoofi.me
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add domain to etc/hosts:

```
GNU nano 5.4                       /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
::1     localhost localhost.localdomain
185.180.204.163 kvm49444605
185.180.204.163 zoofi.me www.zoofi.me
```

and perform reload.

Now, when I point to domain http://zoofi.me page is not found, but on http://185.180.204.163/ instead on Debian test page I receive index.html which should belong to zoofi.me.

Something is missing in this configuration?
I you need more info - ask, I will deliver what is necessary.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers, allows others to use copy-paste  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: The root of your problem is the CNAME record `zoofi.me.  3600 IN CNAME www.zoofi.me.` that you created. That breaks your domain.  Remove that record and create  `A` records for `zoofi.me.` and `www.zoofi.me.` with your servers IP-address instead

Comment: @HBruijn in addition www.zoofi.me is not defined.

Comment: Either you've fixed the problem, you didn't wait for the DNS changes to propagate or your local DNS is broken - http://zoofi.me/ now returns "Congratulations! Your zoofi.me server succeeded!" with a 200 status.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I modified records per your instructions and it's working. Thank you for quick help.